# Remember height of textarea for edit/ posting?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, editor, preferences

It would be nice if the SO backend would save users' desired height of THIS textearea (I'm writing there right now) for later use. I'm tired of resizing it every time I access editor:

[image: http://lulzimg.com/i24/6ada24.png]

Comment: I *like* that it starts over. Though there are some cases where I expand the text area to read a particularly long post, I want it to return to "normal" size the next time I go to post.

Comment: yea, there could be also checkbox after you resize it: "keep it?" "yes" "no"

Comment: I just wish it worked, on Chrome or Firefox (touchscreen).